# Android - Retrofit2 - Kotlin: REST API response different format than model

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

The rest api i'm using returns a response like this (weather api, here i'm querying a city by name):

```
{
    "name": "LA",
    "main": {
        "temp": 5.5,
        "min_temp": 1,
        "max_temp": 8
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to parse it to this object:

```
class City(val name: String, val temp: Double, val temp_min: Double, val temp_max: Double)
```

I'm using the GsonConverterFactory, but it only managers to find the city name. How do I get other properties too, even if they're stored in a nested JSON object?

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `data class` and `json` contains two objects.

```
data class City(val name: String, val main: Main)
data class Main(val temp: Double, val min_temp: Int, val max_temp: Int)
```

That's it

Comment: Thank you! One more question: is there also a way to do this without using multiple classes, or is this considered the best way?

Comment: @DreamsInHD`class` represents json object with all structure. You may not declaring some values in `data class` if it's ignored but to get inner json object you have to come through all hierarchy